# Log queries accessed by particular user for all tables in single database postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, logging

I am in need of logging all the SQL queries accessed by a particular user for single database. I had tried below

```
ALTER ROLE test_user SET log_statement TO 'all';
```

While checking the logs it seems to be logging the queries accessed by the user `test_user`, But I could find the logs for other queries too, like the below:

```
statement: SELECT pg_catalog.quote_ident(c.relname) FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c WHERE c.relkind IN ('r', 'S', 'v', 'm', 'f', 'p') AND substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(c.relname),1,18)='table_name' AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid) AND c.relnamespace <> (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE nspname = 'pg_catalog')
```

To be clean and to optimize the storage occupied by the log, I want to log the queries accessed by this user alone (Not for all users) and only for all the tables in a specific database without logging the queries internally used by Postgres, Is there any other ways to achieve this? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

As @jjanes pointed the additional logs for pg_catalog were logged when I do tab completion on the table names, Also, it doesn't log this info while trying from superuser, It logs it only for `test_user`. And I could see the username as well on the log along with the database info. Please find the example log below:

```
2020-12-15 05:48:34 UTC:91.241.19.84(46672):pgsql@postgres:[15559]:DETAIL: Role "pgsql" does not exist.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 13: "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5"
2020-12-15 05:48:45 UTC:157.49.192.241(52106):test_user@foobar:[12991]:LOG: statement: SELECT pg_catalog.quote_ident(c.relname) FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c WHERE c.relkind IN ('r', 'S', 'v', 'm', 'f', 'p') AND substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(c.relname),1,11)='table_name_for_tab_completion' AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid) AND c.relnamespace <> (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE nspname = 'pg_catalog')
UNION
SELECT pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.' FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n WHERE substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.',1,11)='table_name_for_tab_completion' AND (SELECT pg_catalog.count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(nspname) || '.',1,11) = substring('table_name_for_tab_completion',1,pg_catalog.length(pg_catalog.quote_ident(nspname))+1)) > 1
UNION
SELECT pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.' || pg_catalog.quote_ident(c.relname) FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c, pg_catalog.pg_namespace n WHERE c.relnamespace = n.oid AND c.relkind IN ('r', 'S', 'v', 'm', 'f', 'p') AND substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.' || pg_catalog.quote_ident(c.relname),1,11)='table_name_for_tab_completion' AND substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.',1,11) = substring('table_name_for_tab_completion',1,pg_catalog.length(pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname))+1) AND (SELECT pg_catalog.count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(nspname) || '.',1,11) = substring('table_name_for_tab_completion',1,pg_catalog.length(pg_catalog.quote_ident(nspname))+1)) = 1
LIMIT 1000
2020-12-15 05:48:46 UTC:157.49.192.241(52106):test_user@foobar:[12991]:LOG: statement: SELECT pg_catalog.quote_ident(c.relname) FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c WHERE c.relkind IN ('r', 'S', 'v', 'm', 'f', 'p') AND substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(c.relname),1,17)='table_name_for_tab_completion' AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid) AND c.relnamespace <> (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE nspname = 'pg_catalog')
UNION
SELECT pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.' FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n WHERE substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.',1,17)='table_name_for_tab_completion' AND (SELECT pg_catalog.count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(nspname) || '.',1,17) = substring('table_name_for_tab_completion',1,pg_catalog.length(pg_catalog.quote_ident(nspname))+1)) > 1
UNION
SELECT pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.' || pg_catalog.quote_ident(c.relname) FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c, pg_catalog.pg_namespace n WHERE c.relnamespace = n.oid AND c.relkind IN ('r', 'S', 'v', 'm', 'f', 'p') AND substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.' || pg_catalog.quote_ident(c.relname),1,17)='table_name_for_tab_completion' AND substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.',1,17) = substring('table_name_for_tab_completion',1,pg_catalog.length(pg_catalog.quote_ident(n.nspname))+1) AND (SELECT pg_catalog.count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE substring(pg_catalog.quote_ident(nspname) || '.',1,17) = substring('table_name_for_tab_completion',1,pg_catalog.length(pg_catalog.quote_ident(nspname))+1)) = 1
LIMIT 1000
2020-12-15 05:48:48 UTC:157.49.192.241(52106):test_user@foobar:[12991]:LOG: statement: select count(*) from table_name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply it to just one user in just one database, you can just add the database to the statement:

```
ALTER ROLE test_user IN DATABASE foobar SET log_statement TO 'all';
```

Of course you would also have to undo the less specific you used first:

```
ALTER ROLE test_user RESET log_statement;
```

As for the specific query you showed us, you didn't show any evidence that is **not** for that user in the first place.  It looks like the type of query that might be issued by a client program for something like introspection or tab-completion.  These are issued as the user on behalf of the user by the user's client, the database server has no way to suppress them.